# Saving data to database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have made method `SaveRecord` in `CurrentMovie` class for saving data to database hosted on Azure.

```
public class CurrentMovie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> release { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }

    public void SaveRecord(int? ID, string title, Nullable<int> release, string image)
    {
            var context = new movie_generationsEntities();
            var movie_record = new movie_generations();

            ID = movie_record.movieID;
            title = movie_record.title;
            release = movie_record.release;
            image = movie_record.image;              

            context.movie_generations.Add(movie_record);
            context.SaveChanges();                                       
    }
}
```

Then I call this method in `controller`.

```
var movieDB = new CurrentMovie();
movieDB.SaveRecord(movieDB.ID, movieDB.title, movieDB.release, movieDB.image);
```

I am certain that data are saved in `movieDB` properties because I save them to `ViewBag` and successfully display them. Connection to the database is successful because it just saves empty rows with no expected data.

Is there something wrong or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create a new CurrentMovie object and save it before setting its properties and obviously, all its properties are equal to the default value of their types.

Comment: It may look like that from my example but movieDB object is initialized before I save data into its properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values from the new object to the parameters, when you wanted the exact opposite. Also, you don't need those properties in your class.

Your code should look like this:

```
public class CurrentMovie
{
    public void SaveRecord(int? ID, string title, int? release, string image)
    {
        var context = new movie_generationsEntities();
        var movie_record = new movie_generations();

        movie_record.movieID = ID;
        movie_record.title = title;
        movie_record.release = release;
        movie_record.image = image;              

        context.movie_generations.Add(movie_record);
        context.SaveChanges();          
    }
}
```

Comment: remove properties from class no need there, you have declare those in function parameter then try

Comment: and also share DBContext class where you have define movie_generations

Comment: namespace RandomMovieGenerator.DBModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class movie_generationsEntities : DbContext
    {
        public movie_generationsEntities()
            : base("name=movie_generationsEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<movie_generations> movie_generations { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: I had no errors, it just made empty rows in database. Now I have made some adjustments and I get System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.' on this line context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Id is nullable in database? here you pass nullable may be that was the issue

Comment: In my Database I have ID which is auto incremented with each row and movieID. So it should not be an issue.

Comment: I have updated this answer to reflect what Hitesh meant from the comments. Please try using this and post the exact error (look at InnerException) if it throws any

Comment: then in your function parameter set it not nullable remove ? mark from int make only int ID

Comment: @HiteshKansagara I moved forward but I ran into another issue. Nvm, thank you for your assistance.